# What do dusk and dawn count as in Fury of Dracula 3rd ed?

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In the 3rd edition, the rulebook says

> Dawn occurs before the day, and dusk occurs before the night.

Does this mean that dawn = night, and dusk = day when resolving combat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, what edition are you talking about? If I'm assuming third correctly, then:

> If combat is at dusk or night, Dracula resolves the “at night” effects of his combat cards.

thus dusk = night; dawn = day for combat effects.

Comment: Yes this is third edition

Answer (score 0):

I believe this wouldn't make sense thematically.  With the idea of Dusk and Dawn, they both occur at the end of the light/dark cycle i.e Dawn is the end of night and the Dusk is the end of the day.

It therefore make much more thematic sense that `Dawn = day` and `Dusk = night`

Even if the wording of the rules don't quite read correctly, I would stick with common usage of the English terms for the game.

Comment: Many games, especially FFG ones, use very specific terminology that not always mean what you expect it to mean. Trying to use "common english meaning" or "thematic sense" in these cases is more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Clearly the rules were loosely written, so using common sense is necessary to interpret them.

Answer (score -2):

I think the thing to keep in mind is that it's a vampire game. At dusk, Dracula is waking up and ready to feed/fight, and he's got all night to do so. At dawn, he's in a hurry to get back into his coffin before sunrise, and he's getting weaker every minute that passes, therefore he's weaker at dawn than he is at dusk.

Comment: Hi Caelin, and welcome to the site. Please check out our [tour] to see how the site works -- you might have mistaken this place for behaving like a discussion forum, but we expect answers (such as you've provided here) to directly and fully answer the question, rather than provide discussion points. It may make sense to consider the narrative sensibilities of the game, but ultimately that should be backed up by a citation of the game's rules itself!